# How to submit an independant Apple Watch app?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

Now that WatchOS 6 is out, Apple told us that we could develop standalone app for Apple Watch. I did, but now, how can I submit the app watch in Itunes connect ?

When I'm clicking on "new app", I can only choose "IOS" or "TvOS"....

Thank you for your help

Comment: Just guessing here, but have you tried this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps#3226960

Comment: I've read this documentation. My app is Independent, I'm sure. But how do I upload it to the Apple Store ?

Comment: Choose iOS and then just upload your app as a watch only app.

Comment: and where do you choose "watch only app" ?

Comment: You don't choose it anywhere in App Store Connect.  You choose it when you create the project in Xcode and then just upload it as normal.